# Change value of string inside list

Tags: c#, pointers

maybe its a rookie question, but I need to change value of string inside List.

```
public string TopU1_N;
private List<string> TopScores;

void Start()
{
    TopScores = new List<string>();

    TopScores.Add(TopU1_N);
    TopScores.Add(TopU2_N);

    TopScores[0]="100";
    TopScores[1]="200";

    print("Top1: " + TopU1_N);
    print("Top2: " + TopU2_N);
}
```

I need to print such result: 100,200.
This is written for unity

Comment: What problem are you having? And what does it have to do with pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET strings are immutable types. This means that even if you change the value of `TopScores[0]` it will not affect the value of `TopU1_N` that you have previously assigned.

In order to achieve this you need to use a `List<SomeType>`.

For example:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
SomeType myType = new SomeType();
myType.Value = "OLD VALUE";

List<SomeType> list = new List<SomeType>();
list.Add(myType);
list[0].Value = "NEW VALUE";

Console.WriteLine(myType.Value); // prints NEW VALUE
```

Comment: You can also add an implicit casting to string from SomeType in order to make it's read consumption easier.

Comment: This isn't about the immutability of strings. It's about the fact that it's copying the reference to the string and while the reference in the list is changed the original variable reference isn't.

Comment: If you are lazy, you can use `Tuple<string>`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use unsafe code for doing what you want .
I think this might work.

```
    public string TopU1_N;
    public string TopU2_N;
    private object TopScores;

    void Start()
    {

       unsafe
       { 

        TopScores = new List<string *>();   

        TopScores.Add(&TopU1_N);
        TopScores.Add(&TopU2_N);

        *(TopScores[0])="100";
        *(TopScores[1])="200";

        print("Top1: " + TopU1_N);
        print("Top2: " + TopU2_N);
    }
}
```

Please try compiling it.

Comment: You can't use type `string*`, as `string` is a managed type. Nevertheless, pointer types cannot be used as generic type arguments. You probably want to modify the string in the memory, which is really bad and not recommended at all.